# What is the expected number of times to pass Go before landing on Boardwalk

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

This question just pertains to the monopoly board; that is, no actual functionalities of the game(chance cards, go to jail, etc.). The only mechanism to move forward is the rolling of the two dice. The expected number of passes of Go before landing on the 36th square boardwalk.

I interpret this question as the following:
If we imagine the sequence of squares as the sequence of natural numbers, and counting the first square as a passing of Go, it is the following expectation: $$E(\frac{X}{36} | (X \bmod 36 = 0))$$ Where X is the current position on the board, or current number in the sequence. How do I compute this expectation?

Comment: Are you asking about the actual game of Monopoly or some abstraction of it?  If you mean the actual game, I strongly advise simulation.  There are far too many odd occurrences to consider (cards that advance you or set you back, going to Jail, and so on).

Comment: @lulu A simplification of it, just considering the monopoly board. I have should have delineated this in the question, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I also don't understand what $X$ is in this scenario.  Presumably we are starting at $0$, the "Go" square, right?  I do see the value in computing the expectation starting at other squares, however.  You get a good set of equations that way, such as $E_{35}=\frac 1{36}\times 0+\frac 2{26}\times (E_0+1)+\cdots$ (N.B.  I may have my numbering of the squares off, but I think the point should be clear).  If you don't mind solving a system of $36$ or $37$ linear equations, the problem should be easy enough.

Comment: I would still probably use simulation for this... the distribution of die rolls is probably going to make this quite difficult to compute analytically.

Comment: @user6247850  I don't think it should be too bad.  Considering states (one for each square) it's easy to get linear equations connecting them. Granted, $36$ simultaneous linear equations are hard to solve by hand, but machines are good at this sort of thing.

Comment: @lulu We start at Go(which I counted as 1). What I meant by X is our most recent position. However our variable expectation is n, the number of times before X mod 36 == 0. So really I should have stated it as such E(n | X mod 36 = 0). One other thing to note is that apparently the answer(unverified) to this question was 10, using the Strong Markov Property, though I'm unsure how to get that.

Comment: I still don't understand the notation nor the square naming.  If you have $36$ squares numbered $\{0, \cdots, 35\}$ then Boardwalk should be $\#35$, right?  Not terribly important, but still.  Anyway, as I said I would create states, one for each square, write down all the linear equations connecting them, and then ask a machine to solve them.  $36\times 36$ is a lot by hand, but incidental to a computer.

Comment: Note:   I don't see a quick way to get to the number $10$.  I'd have guessed smaller...since you hit (roughly) $\frac 17$ of the squares each round (and you get the first round for free) then I'd have thought the answer would be around $7$.  But, of course, this is a pretty crude computation (and for all I know if you hit Boardwalk on the first round you mean that to count as $1$, not $0$).

Comment: Where does $36$ come from? Doesn't a monopoly board have $40$ squares?

Comment: @lulu I hadn't read your comment before posting my answer (which is essentially just a copy of your comment, sorry), but you might be interested to hear that computer simulations confirm your back-of-the-envelope calculation.

Comment: @MikeEarnest  Oh, thanks for running the simulation.  Yeah, I'd have been very surprised to see that my crude estimate was far off the mark but of course if does happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer:** On average, you will pass Go *approximately* seven times before hitting Boardwalk (where your very first move counts as passing Go).

**Explanation:** Each turn, you move forward seven squares on average. This means you land on about one seventh of the squares of board on average during each pass around the board. In particular, during each revolution, there is about a one seventh chance you will hit Boardwalk. Therefore, it will take approximately seven revolutions on average to land on boardwalk.

This is only an approximate answer, but computer simulations confirm it is very close to the truth. [See for yourself.](https://tio.run/##bVJNa@MwEL3rV8yml4S43oSUQgsp7F7KXvawH4eFglHssSMqS640jgmlvz07kpwmLdEhJqM3T2/mvW5PW2tWh0PtbAtOmoo/qu2so/hPGRKiwhoqhdPZvQA@V/ALqXcG5LHB9O0GHWyQBkQDS@Ay3OYR7RJ2JJsus9tZYmytsZ3V@8Kr9kT9M1HRFsG/9NKhhyhtAWRhdZfDiPsdL7msPDzaHP7ZHjxJli0pFCKs7J1DQ0VigjUsxu4/TK@MIiU1aJQ7ZRqwNfdBaXtDHqSHTnof6o82A29hwBP/MtHz2AWpFn0RsFgVjeU3lvEu/gxbpfGzii9rnuOeRfw1pDTsWfhWEXy30lWD1M8wHYGru1lkuTDJfJ0Mgfn4ZU@s1kCD5UKJGW93h1BbNzArbPZhocqB79t3SlV/Zn0Yhf2oo6owFDQ8vawq9pTG5eTvDBeEXa/hZvEBcGlJ8@OWjuc8KZcahIhVx375sOIFHyFkWfZtdJUHhXjLroaoNTg9NYzZSmh@@mPwkludC@GcTCbiW02cP77qtaTg/@tbovZZTKXcoZMNHjPPqYliQ3aGMTVYgdgga8LgbCQ5uRtAr285P/Ukcsa0ks60Zknm1zP1YnY4/Ac)

Comment: Interesting, I guess 10 wasn't the right answer, and that there was no intuitive way to really calculate the answer was also surprising. Thanks!

Comment: To stress: I find the linear system method (sketched in the comments) to be entirely intuitive. The problem is clearly non-trivial, I'd say, because the dice rolls are not uniformly distributed.  That averages out in the long run, of course, but who knows what it does in the early rounds?

Answer (score 0):

For an exact calculation:

Number the fields from 0 (go) to 39 (boardwalk). Let $E_k$ be the expected number of times you reach or pass Go before reaching Boardwalk if you are located on field k. We ignore the “go to jail” field, which would move you from field 30 to field 10.

By definition, $E_{39} = 0$. For other fields, there are 11 possible moves, with different probabilities, of which some may reach or pass Go. For each k we write down the formula, for example $E_{35}$ = $E_{37} / 36$ + $2 * E_{38} / 36$ + $3 * E_{39} / 36$ + $4*(1+E_0)/36$ + $5*(1+E_1)/36$ + …

This is a linear system of 39 equations since $E_{39}=0$. We change the equations $E_{38}$, $E_{37}$ ,,, $E_{10}$ to be in terms of $E_0$ to $E_{10}$. We then have $E_{10}$ on both sides of the equation, which lets us express $E_{10}$ in terms of $E_0$ to $E_9$ only, we substitute this for $E_{10}$ in all the other equations.

The same is done for $E_9$ to $E_0$, which finally reduces all the numbers $E_0$ to $E_{38}$ to constants. They will all be different, for example $E_{38}$ will be about one larger than $E_0$ to $E_{10}$.